# How to pass comma separated Php dynamic params in javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to pass comma separated Php dynamic params in javascript onclick function. Can anybody help me with the correct fix? The following does not workout.

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='editUser(". $row['pub_name'] .",". $row['name'] .",". $row['email_id'] .")'>Edit</a></td>";
```

JavaScript:

```
function editUser(id, pm, email) {
    alert(id);
    alert(pm);
    alert(email);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you get your data in a JSON object ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the values are strings, you need to put quotes around them:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='editUser(\"". $row['pub_name'] ."\",\"". $row['name'] ."\",\"". $row['email_id'] ."\")'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Also note that it's considered *much* better practice to use unobtrusive JS code to attach your event handlers, over the outdated `on*` event attributes. As you've tagged jQuery you could to this:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" data-pubname="'.$row['pub_name'].'" data-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-emailid="'.$row['email_id'].'">Edit</a></td>';
```

```js
$('td a').click(function(e) { // change selector as appropriate here
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this);
    console.log($el.data('pubname'));
    console.log($el.data('name'));
    console.log($el.data('emailid'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to change the below line..

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='editUser(". $row['pub_name'] .",". $row['name'] .",". $row['email_id'] .")'>Edit</a></td>"
```

to

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='editUser('". $row['pub_name'] ."','". $row['name'] ."','". $row['email_id'] .'")'>Edit</a></td>"
```

because when `PHP` display this line and you clicked on the button than it is going to found the variable name, so simply put the `'` so it become the `string` not the `variable` name.

Answer (score 0):

They need to be quoted, you can change the quotes as follows:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick=\"editUser('". $row['pub_name'] ."','".
     $row['name'] ."','". $row['email_id'] ."')\">Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

```
// Using arrays
$baz = array("value" => "foo");
echo "this is {$baz['value']} !"; // this is foo !
```

Solution:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='editUser('{$row['pub_name']}', '{$row['name']}', '{$row['email_id']}')'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Comment: the values still need to be quoted

Answer (score 0):

Better to use HTML code otherwise it will be complicated:

```
<a href="#" onclick="editUser('<?=$row['pub_name']?>','<?=$row['name']?>','<?=$row['email_id']?>')">EDIT</a>
```